# Critical section in multithreading for ip scanner

Tags: multithreading, delphi, synchronization, delphi-7, critical-section

Hello i have doubt about critical section. I have two threads scannerThread  and scannerchild thread.Code for Scannerthread is mentioned below.

```
procedure ScannerThread.Execute;
var
  I: Integer;
  ScannerCh: Array of ScannerChild;
  IpList: TStringlist;
  IPCount: Integer;
begin
  IpList:=TStringList.Create;
  IF GetNumberOfIpsInRange(Ip_From, Ip_To, IpList) then // Function call that returns iplist if TRUE
  begin
    Try
      if Assigned(LvHosts) then // Clear
        LvHosts.Clear;
      IPCount := IpList.Count;
      SetLength(ScannerCh, IPCount);
        I := 0;
        repeat
          while GetTThreadsCount(GetCurrentProcessId) > tcount do // Tcount is threads to create which is given by user     
            Sleep(10);
          ScannerCh[I]:=ScannerChild.Create(True, IpList[i]);
          ScannerCh[I].FreeOnTerminate := True;
          ScannerCh[I].LvHostname := LvHosts;
          ScannerCh[I].Resume;
          Inc(I);
        until I = IPCount;
      if Assigned(IpList) Then
        FreeAndNil(IpList);
    except
      ShowMessage('Operation Failed');
      If Assigned(IpList) Then
         FreeAndNil(IpList);
    end;
  end else
    ShowMessage('Invalid Range');
  repeat
   Sleep(100);
  Until GetTThreadsCount(GetCurrentProcessId) = 2;

end;
```

Code for Scannerchild is mentioned below

```
procedure ScannerChild.AddToList;
begin
  ListItems1 := LVHostName.Items.Add;
  ListItems1.Caption := IPToScan;
  ListItems1.SubItems.Add(IPAddrToName(IPToScan));
end;

procedure ScannerChild.AddToList1;
begin
  ListItems1:=LVHostName.Items.Add;
  ListItems1.Caption := IPToScan;
  ListItems1.SubItems.Add('No host found');
end;

procedure ScannerChild.Execute;
Var
  ListItems1 : TListItem;
  Hostname   : String;
begin       
    Hostname := IPAddrToName(IPToScan);
    if Hostname <> EmptyStr then
    begin
      Synchronize(AddToList);
    end else
      synchronize(AddToList1);
end;
```

Here I am getting output but it is not serialised. Like thread which getting created first is not getting displayed first. if I put ip range 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.10 then I should get serialised output in listview like

```
 192.168.0.1     hostname
 192.168.0.2     hostname
 192.168.0.3     hostname
 .
 .
 192.168.0.10    hostname
```

But i am not getting it.my output is coming like

```
    192.168.0.1    hostname
    192.168.0.2    hostname
    192.168.0.4    hostname 
    192.168.0.6    hostname
    192.168.0.3    hostname
```

So is it because I am not using critical section? Nnd if yes, where should I acquire and leave critical section so that thread created first can enter critical section first and next thread next like this.

Comment: It looks like ScannerChild is updating a VCL control. You cannot do this in a thread.

Comment: Indeed you cannot access GUI controls from outside the main thread. Beyond that your design is awry. You really need to separate the scanning logic from the GUI.

Comment: nope there is main form which has these threads

Comment: @DavidHeffernan these two threads are part of form which has listview to display output

Comment: Negative. You must not access VCL controls from a thread other than the GUI thread. Your code quite clearly breaks that rule. My other point stands.

Comment: ScanneCh is gui thread only which updates gui

Comment: Negative. The `ScannerChild` class clearly derives from `TThread`. Hence it having `FreeOnTerminate`, `Resume`, `Execute`. Ergo, the code in `ScannerChild.Execute` executes away from the GUI thread. You would do well to provide a complete program, suitably cut-down to a minimal sample. There are numerous other problems.

Comment: It depends all on the thread context. If you access any VCL controls from a thread context different to `MainThreadId` then you are in trouble. You can use a simple check for that `if MainThreadId = TThread.CurrentThread.TreadId then AccessVCL else DoNotAccessVCL;`

Comment: In fact it does not matter who started the thread, it only matters in which thread context the code is running. To temporarily switch back to the *MainThread* context use `Synchronize` or `Queue`.

Comment: @sir rufo i edited my code and used synchronize command

Comment: The order you are getting the results from the worker threads are not predictable. You will have to do that by numbering the threads and getting that number when they finish.

Comment: Why would you expect the values to arrive in any particular order? Do you understand that threads operate independently?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes sir i know threads operate independntly it is cpu bound task so os handles it.

Comment: Threads behave like people in real life. Give 100 persons nearly the same job to do and they will not return in the order you gave them the job. If so it is just a lucky moment but nothing you can count on.

Comment: Since you know that threads operate independently, I can't understand why you would expect one thread to do its work before another one. That would imply dependence. And, FWIW, these tasks are categorically not CPU bound. But threads will likely have benefit because you will make the synchronous network communications appear to behave asynchronously. I think.

Comment: @gastonramirez Think about how you would do this in real life (with some people for the work) to get the job done. Write a list with all the ip to scan, hand over one ip to a person to get the hostname, if he returns write the hostname behind the ip. Now the order is as you like, but your app did not behave like this ;o)

Comment: What you really need to do is separate the scanning from the UI. Once you do that then you can begin to work out how to present the results of the scanning in a clean manner. Mixing all these aspects together makes it very hard for you to see and understand your problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Threads execute in parallel, independently of each other. Unless you impose some synchronisation or serialisation between the threads, the order in which they complete their tasks is unpredictable.

I suggest that you don't attempt to update the UI in a particular order because doing so will either hinder the performance of your scan, or make your code much more complex.

I do have a number of comments:

1. Separate the scanning from the UI. Such a design is cleaner and allows you to concentrate on each aspect independently. The way to make this happen is to store the results of the scan in a non-visual structure and then arrange that the GUI presents a view of this structure.
2. Don't hold references of free on terminate threads once you've started the thread because the reference can go stale any time.
3. Don't create threads to handle a single address. Use a thread pool.
4. Don't sleep.
5. Your code leaks `IpList`. Learn how to use `finally`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other good advice here, I'll recommend that you look at UThreadStringList by Tilo Eckert.  Code is posted and explained here: http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=2167
It's a thread-safe TStringList, with critical section locks built-in.  You use it just like any TStringlist, so you could just stuff all of your results into it, then sort, then assign back into your UI when all threads are done.
If you wanted to implement a thread pool, you could have one UThreadStringList to act as a work queue, and then another to hold the results.

Comment: About a thread safe string list, Indy also ships with a thread safe string list, the `TIdThreadSafeStringList` class from IdThreadSafe unit.